# how to implement an onclick listener for a list view that links to a new fragment

Tags: android, listview, fragment, onclicklistener

So I have a listview that works, but I want to implement an onclick listener for this listview. I want the onclick listener to link to a new fragment so that another page is opened when I click on some index in the list. I have done some testing and have determined that the onclick listener as a whole does not work.

This is what I have so far:

```
package ca.queensu.engsoc.events;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class eventList extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener
{
public static final String KEY_NAME = "NAME_KEY";
ListView events;
String[] e;
mockData myBadData = new mockData();
@Override

protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    //Fragment fragment_blank2=new SomeFragment();

    e = myBadData.getData();

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.event_list);

    events=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.dayList);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,e);

    events.setAdapter(adapter);

    events.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}

@Override

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, final int i, long l)
{
    //TextView temp=(TextView) view;

    View temp=view;

    //final Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, temp.getText() + "" + i, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT.show());

    temp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

            bundle.putString(KEY_NAME,myBadData.getOneData(i));

            Fragment fr = new event_description();

            fr.setArguments(bundle);

            FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();

            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();

            int contId = v.getId();

            fragmentTransaction.replace(contId, fr);

            fragmentTransaction.commit();

            Intent i=new Intent(eventList.this, fr.getClass());

        }
    });
}
```

}

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Actually as far as I understand you don't need to set any additional click listeners.
onItemClick() method should do the stuff.
final int i this is position of clicked view if you need one.

Answer (score 0):

To do what you want first you need to declare a interface to use as callback between your adapter and your activity/fragment.

RecyclerItemCallback:

```
public interface RecyclerItemCallback {

    void onClick(int position);

}
```

Then make your activity implement this interface: (

```
public class EventList extends Activity implements RecyclerItemCallback {

    ...

    @Override
    public void onClick(int position) {
        //Implement the method "Fragment getFragment(int position)" to find the Fragment you want based on the position
        YourFragment newFragment = getFragment(position);
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        if (addToBackStack) {
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(newFragment.getClass().getSimpleName());
        }
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content, newFragment).commitAllowingStateLoss();
    }
}
```

Then in your adapter do this:

YourAdapter

```
public class YourAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<YourAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private RecyclerItemCallback recyclerCallback;
    private ArrayList<YourObject> list;
    private Context context;
    private int lastPosition;

    public NewsAdapter(Context context, RecyclerItemCallback callback) {
        this.context = context;
        this.newsList = new ArrayList<>();
        this.recyclerCallback = callback;
    }
    ...


    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView text1;
        ...
        private View.OnClickListener onRowClicked = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            recyclerCallback.onItemClick(getAdapterPosition());
        }
    };

    MyViewHolder(View itemView, int viewType) {
        super(itemView);
        this.viewType = viewType;
        ...
        itemView.setOnClickListener(onRowClicked);
    }
    ...
}
```